# how can I center my text in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a plain html code:

```css
    section.cta, section.cta2, section.cta3, section.cta4 {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      padding: 250px 0;
    }
    section.cta .cta-content, section.cta2 .cta2-content, section.cta3 .cta3-content,  section.cta4 .cta4-content {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    section.cta .cta-content h2, section.cta2 .cta2-content h2, section.cta3 .cta3-content h2, section.cta4 .cta4-content h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      color: black;
      max-width: 450px;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
    
    section.cta .cta-content p  {
      color: black;
      max-width: 450px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    section.cta {
      background-image: url('https://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/files/2011/08/bliss.jpg');
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      section.cta .cta-content h2, section.cta2 .cta2-content h2, section.cta3 .cta3-content h2, section.cta4 .cta4-content h2 {
        font-size: 80px;
      }
    }
    section.cta .overlay {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<section class="cta">
        <div class="cta-content">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>this is header</h2>
                <p>this is some other text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </section>
```

The result is a page with a nice background and a text aligned to the left.

Basically the text looks like this:

```
|   this is header                                   |
|   this is some other text.                         |
```

and it is on the very left side of the background when user looks at the webpage on full screen. I want to change it, so that the text is visible like this:

```
|                  this is header                    |
|              this is some other text               |
```

How can I do that?

My jsfiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0zfktus3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0zfktus3/2/

Comment: Take the `max-width` off of the `h2` and `p` and then add `text-align:center;` to the container. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zfktus3/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `max-width` from the `h2` and `p`.

Add a class of `text-center` to the container.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a bootstrap class **`text-center`** to center all the text inside an element.

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zfktus3/4/)

The updated HTML for `.container` would be as follows

```
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h2>this is header</h2>
        <p>this is some other text.</p>
    </div>
```

Please read the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) to know more about the **Bootstrap Alignment classes**

Comment: @user3766930...first one to answer..so sad.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Add the class "text-center" to the container div.

```
<section class="cta">
     <div class="cta-content">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h2>this is header</h2>
            <p>this is some other text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use css to align it in centre  all following code to your css

```
h2{
  text-align:center;
}

p{
  text-align:center;
}
```